# Need help excluding certain rows from joined tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a game that uses MySQL. I'm trying to show a list of final game scores, and this list should exclude anyone whom the user has blocked. 
Here are the table structures:

```
table_game
------------
table_id    int
person_id   int
person_nom  varchar(25)
finalscore  int
scoretime   datetime

table_blocked
--------------
table_id    int
person_id   int
person_id_blocked   int
```

Let's say my person_id is '1' and I've blocked person_id '5' (so there is a row in table_blocked with table_id = 1, person_id = 1, person_id_blocked = 5). 
This means I should not see person_id '5' in my results.

Here's the query, but person_id '5' is showing up in the results:

```
SELECT
  f.table_id,
  f.person_id as fID,
  f.person_nom AS fNOM,
  f.finalscore AS fFINAL,
  f.scoretime AS fTIME,
  table_blocked.table_id,
  table_blocked.person_id,
  table_blocked.person_id_blocked 
FROM
  table_game f 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table_blocked ON f.person_id = table_blocked.person_id  
WHERE (
  (fFINAL > 0)
   AND ((table_blocked.person_id_blocked != '5') OR (table_blocked.person_id_blocked IS NULL))
)  
ORDER BY fTIME DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: The SQL is not even syntactically correct as written.  `ffinal` is a column alias, so it cannot be referenced in the `where` clause (or the data structure is super confusing by having a column by that name as well as a column aliased to that name).

Comment: Thanks - I am a PHP programmer and a MySQL novice. Didn't know that aliases weren't allowed in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes it is.  I think a clearer way of writing the query is:

```
SELECT f.table_id, f.person_id as fID, f.person_nom AS fNOM, f.finalscore AS fFINAL,
       f.scoretime AS fTIME, table_blocked.table_id, table_blocked.person_id,   
       tb.person_id_blocked 
FROM table_game f
WHERE f.person_id not in (select person_id_blocked from table_blocked) and
      f.finalscore > 0
```

This would then turn into:

```
SELECT f.table_id, f.person_id as fID, f.person_nom AS fNOM, f.finalscore AS fFINAL,
       f.scoretime AS fTIME, table_blocked.table_id, table_blocked.person_id,   
       tb.person_id_blocked 
FROM table_game f LEFT OUTER JOIN
     table_blocked tb
     ON f.person_id = tb.person_id_blocked
WHERE tb.person_id_blocked is null and
      f.finalscore > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please post an example specifically excluding a person if their person_id_blocked = 5? This query is being called from a PHP page so I can dynamically insert the number of person_id_blocked.

Comment: @user3184415 . . . If you know the *person being blocked* then just include `where personid <> $blockedpersonid`.  You don't need to join to the table at all.

Comment: I appreciate your input. I have to join the 2 tables because I'm displaying a list of scores for the game. table_game contains the person's info, such as their id number and score(s) for games, and the other table, table_blocked, needs to be joined so that if a user has blocked another user, the blocked user won't be able to see the scores of the person who blocked them. I tried person_id_blocked != 5 (original posted query) but it's not working.